# Marshmallow Permissions Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-6.0-marshmallow

We are working with Unity3d to build a GPS app.
On an Android device with Marshmallow 6.0, it does not ask for any permissions at the time we install it. We have read that Marshmallow ask for them only at Run Time (https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), but we don´t know how to modify the AndroidManifest to do it properly. Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36814627/3785314). Please try to search the question before posting.

In Android 6.0 Marshmallow, Android permission is now asked when during **run-time** instead of **install** time. There is nothing you can do about that. 
Modifying the AndroidManifest won't solve the problem.

This is a bug that is now fixed in **Unity 5.4.0B15**.

**Unity 5.4.0B15** Android Marshmallow - Fixed issues when querying for custom permissions.

Update to [5.4.0B15](http://unity3d.com/unity/beta) or above to fix this problem.

The first time permission is asked, you get something like this

[image]

The second time, the player will have a chance to choose Never ask again.

[image]

The reason for this is to give the user complete control of which permission to allow and which ones to decline. For example, you can allow WiFi but reject Bluetooth unlike before, when you had to either allow every permission or reject all of them.